# How to print a specific line in string Python?

Tags: python, string, web-crawler

So I got a string output out of a css selector while web crawling and the string has 7 lines, 6 of them are useless and I only want the 4th line.

The string is as follows:

```
کارکرد:
۵۰,۰۰۰
رنگ:
سفید
وضعیت بدنه:
بدون رنگ
قیمت صفر : ۳۱۵,۰۰۰,۰۰۰ تومان
```

Is there a way to print only the 4th line?

The crawling code:

```
color = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='col']") 
for c in color:
    print(c.text)
```

Comment: Which variable contains the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course! [See python documentation about list items](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

```
color = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='col']") 
print(color[3].text)
```

> List items are indexed, the first item has index [0], the second item has index [1](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) etc.

Comment: I was trying  'enumerate' and I got confused. It really helped, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want items `one` to `four` try this:

```
for idx in range(4):
    print(color[idx].text)
```

And if you want only `4th` try this: *(in python index in `list` start from `zero`.)*

```
print(color[3].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand the problem correctly, but assuming you have a string with multiple lines, a solution could be:

```
string = '''this string
exists 
on multiple
lines
so lets pick
a line
'''

def select_line(string, line_index):
    return string.splitlines()[line_index]

result = select_line(string,3)

print(result)
```

This function would select the number line you want (index 0 being the first line)